# ContentVersion apex decoding

Tags: apex, contentversion, blob, encoding

we are saving a docx and pdf files in contentversion. But having issue in decoding it back.
Blob.tostring doesnt work as the files encoding is not in the UTF-8 formatting.

Can you please help me reading contentversion ->versiondate (not in UTF-8) formatting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DOCX and PDF are not "encoded" at all--they are binary data formats. You won't be able to easily read these files formats without implementing relevant file readers. DOCX requires a ZIP depression algorithm, while PDF would need to be able to read the PDF format, which is a pretty complicated file format. You won't be able to do anything significant with these kinds of files in Apex.